# Creación de un diccionario ordenado (OrderDict)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo que crear un diccionario ordenado que siga la siguiente estructura:

```
{
        ORDERID : {
            ORDERPRICE : float,
            ORDERDATE: timestamp,
            STATUS: str,
            PRODUCTLINE: str,
            PRODUCTCODE: str,
            CUSTOMERNAME: str,
            CITY: str,
            COUNTRY: str
        }
    }
```

La estructura del diccionario seria algo como: {ORDERID_1: {...}, ORDERID_2: {...},...}

Dispongo de un Dataframe con la siguiente estructura:

```
      ORDERPRICE ORDERDATE     STATUS   PRODUCTLINE  PRODUCTCODE  CUSTOMERNAME      CITY  COUNTRY   
ORDERID                                                     
10107  2871.00  2/24/2003 0:00  Shipped  Motorcycles   S10_1678    Land of Toys Inc. NYC    USA          
10121  2765.90  5/7/2003 0:00   Shipped  Motorcycles   S10_1678    Reims CollectablesReims France
```

He realizado lo siguiente:

```
data_dict = df[['ORDERID','ORDERPRICE','ORDERDATE','STATUS','PRODUCTLINE','PRODUCTCODE','CUSTOMERNAME','CITY','COUNTRY']]

#Agrupo los datos por ORDERID
gb_id = data_dict.groupby('ORDERID')

#Diccionario
d = dict()
for k,v in data_dict.iterrwos():
    m_id = v.pop('ORDERID')
    d[m_id] = v.to_dict()

ordered_d = OrderedDict(d)
ordered_d
```

Pero aparecen varios errores:

1. En primer lugar me muestra el siguiente error:

   `KeyError: "['ORDERID'] not in index"`

Entiendo que ORDERID es el indice de mi dataframe y entonces no esta cogiendo los datos de este. Para solucionar-lo, he creado una nueva columna:

```
df['ORDERID_'] = df.index
```

De todos modos, creo que hay una forma más elegante.

2. Tras haber hecho lo primero, me aparecen el siguiente error donde inicio el for:

   `ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 8: given 2`

Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira a ver si es algo así lo que estás buscando:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

df=pd.DataFrame({'ORDERID':[12107,10121],'ORDERPRICE':[2871.00,2765.90],'ORDERDATE':['2/24/2003 0:00','5/7/2003 0:00'],'STATUS':['Shipped','Shipped']})

df=df.set_index('ORDERID')
df=df.sort_values(['ORDERID'])

orDicc=df.to_dict(orient='index',into=OrderedDict)

print(orDicc)
```

En primer lugar creas el índice `df=df.set_index('ORDERID')`

Ordenas por el campo que quieres `df=df.sort_values(['ORDERID'])`

Y lo conviertes en un diccionario ordenado por índice `orDicc=df.to_dict(orient='index',into=OrderedDict)`

Te daría como resultado (solo he metido algunos de tus datos de ejemplo en el df):

```
OrderedDict([(10121, {'ORDERPRICE': 2765.9, 'ORDERDATE': '5/7/2003 0:00', 'STATUS': 'Shipped'}), (12107, {'ORDERPRICE': 2871.0, 'ORDERDATE': '2/24/2003 0:00', 'STATUS': 'Shipped'})])
```